# Email form wont display on template

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a site that would display some data on my database and a form where people can contact me.

views.py

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail, BadHeaderError
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import ContactForm
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Logo, SkillLanguages, SkillAPI, SkillFrameworks, 
WorkPortfolio, PersonalPortfolio

def index(request):
logo=Logo.objects.all()
skill_languages=SkillLanguages.objects.all()
skill_api=SkillAPI.objects.all()
skill_frameworks=SkillFrameworks.objects.all()
work_portfolio=WorkPortfolio.objects.all()
personal_portfolio=PersonalPortfolio.objects.all()
return render(request, 'johann/index.html', {'logo': logo, 'skill_languages': skill_languages, 'skill_api': skill_api, 'skill_frameworks': skill_frameworks, 'work_portfolio': work_portfolio, 'personal_portfolio': personal_portfolio})


def email(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ContactForm()
else:
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            from_email = form.cleaned_data['from_email']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            try:
                send_mail(name, message, from_email, ['myemail@notsuspiciousmailserver.com'])
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
            return redirect('success')
    return render(request, "johann/index.html", {'form': form})


def success(request):
    return HttpResponse('<script>alert("Success! Thank you for your message."); window.location = "https://pqdrl7qd.apps.lair.io/#contact";</script>')
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^$', views.email, name='email'),
    url(r'^success/$', views.success, name='success'),
]
```

I found out that my problem lies in what I did to the first two URLs, if I switched the email URL and the index URL's places my template would then display my form instead of the data stored in my models and vice versa. What can I do about this?

Comment: Please take a moment to clean up the indentation on your code. Clean, high quality questions are less likely to get closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two url patterns that are identical

```
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
url(r'^$', views.email, name='email'),
```

They will be evaluated in order and the index view will always match first. Once a match is found, the rest of the url patterns are ignored.

You need to come up with a different route for your email view. Might I suggest

```
url(r'^email/$', views.email, name='email'),
```

Comment: I've suspected as much but is there a way that I could display both the form and my model data at the same time on one template? If so how can I achieve that?

Comment: Yes, just create an instance of your form in the same view that you want the form to appear in. Move all the form logic to that view. Pass that form to the template in the context. Tell the form to render in the template.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
url(r'^email/$', views.email, name='email'),
```